# Searching for objects in File Management system with loop

Tags: excel, vba

Can anybody explain why this code does not work correct? If I run this using each cell separately it work fine. However when I run it in loop it works for first object but then it continues to give 0 as result.

My code is searching for objects in our File Management system.

So if I remove loop functionality, add cell value instead of `cel.Value` using  `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("B3").Value` or `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("B4").Value` or `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("B5").Value` and run code by clicking button each time it work correct (I get a message "There were 1 objects" on each click). When I run it as it is I get: "There were 1 objects" then "There were 0 objects", "There were 0 objects"

Here is my code:

```
'set range
Dim myrng: Set myrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("B3:B5")

Dim cel
'loop through each cell in range
For Each cel In myrng

        ' ObjectType
        oExp.DataStatusValueType = MFilesAPI.MFStatusTypeObjectTypeID
        oTV.SetValue MFDatatypeLookup, 305
        oSearchCondition.Set oExp, MFConditionTypeEqual, oTV
        oSearchConditions.Add -1, oSearchCondition

        ' Class
        Set oSearchCondition = CreateObject("MFilesAPI.SearchCondition")
        oExp.DataPropertyValuePropertyDef = MFilesAPI.MFBuiltInPropertyDefClass
        oTV.SetValue MFDatatypeLookup, 177
        oSearchCondition.Set oExp, MFConditionTypeEqual, oTV
        oSearchConditions.Add -1, oSearchCondition

        ' Object has the same name
        Set oSearchCondition = CreateObject("MFilesAPI.SearchCondition")
        oExp.DataPropertyValuePropertyDef = MFilesAPI.MFBuiltInPropertyDefNameOrTitle
        oTV.SetValue MFDatatypetext, cel.Value ' Here it is
        oSearchCondition.Set oExp, MFConditionTypeEqual, oTV
        oSearchConditions.Add -1, oSearchCondition

        ' Object is not deleted
        Set oSearchCondition = CreateObject("MFilesAPI.SearchCondition")
        oExp.DataStatusValueType = MFilesAPI.MFStatusType.MFStatusTypeDeleted
        oTV.SetValue MFDatatypeBoolean, False
        oSearchCondition.Set oExp, MFConditionTypeEqual, oTV
        oSearchConditions.Add -1, oSearchCondition

        ' Execute the search
        Dim oObjectSearchResults As MFilesAPI.ObjectSearchResults
        Set oObjectSearchResults = oVault.ObjectSearchOperations.SearchForObjectsByConditions(oSearchConditions, MFSearchFlagNone, False)

        MsgBox ("There were " & oObjectSearchResults.Count & " objects")

Next
```

Comment: This is probably not the problem and I've never used M-Files, but you're recreating the `oSearchCondition ` object multiple times, when it's likely you only need to do it once. Perhaps you'd have to reset some parameters when you reuse it, but I don't think continually recreating it is necessary. Create it once, before you get into the loop, then change the parameters. In fact, it looks like you're trying to layer multiple criteria for your search. Each time you `CreateObject("MFilesAPI.SearchCondition")` you're effectively wiping out everything before and starting with reset object.

Comment: Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so with a hint from PeterT I have managed to get it working by adding this to the end of the code:

```
        Set oObjectSearchResults = Nothing
        Set oSearchConditions = Nothing
        Set oSearchCondition = Nothing
        Set oExp = Nothing
        Set oTV = Nothing
```